# What's the meaning of つく when it comes to spelling words?

Tags: translation, word-usage

I found a Japanese children's book called [あっちゃんあがつく たべものあいうえお](https://www.ehonnavi.net/ehon/1885/%E3%81%82%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%82%93%E3%81%82%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F%E3%81%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%88%E3%81%8A/). Based on the context, I understand あがつく to mean "words containing あ", so my guess is that つく in this context means "to be affixed to a word".

However, I can't find this sense of つく in any of the senses in its [goo.ne.jp J-J dictionary entry](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8F_%28%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F%29/#:%7E:text=%E3%81%A4%E3%83%BB%E3%81%8F%E3%80%90%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8F%EF%BC%8F%E2%96%BD%E9%99%84%E3%81%8F%EF%BC%8F%E7%9D%80%E3%81%8F%E3%80%91&text=%EF%BC%91%20%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%A8%E4%BB%96,%E9%9B%A2%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82&text=%EF%BC%92%20%EF%BC%88%E7%9D%80%E3%81%8F%EF%BC%89%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8C,%E4%BB%96%E3%81%AE%E6%89%80%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A7%E9%81%94%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82&text=%EF%BC%93%20%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AE%E3%81%9D%E3%81%B0%E3%81%AB%E5%AF%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%9D%E3%81%84%E5%BE%93%E3%81%86%E3%80%82). Have I interpreted the verb correctly?

Comment: Interesting question. Never thought about it.

Comment: The primary sense of 付く is "to be attached" or "to stick", and other meanings [on Jisho](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8F) mostly derive by fairly obvious metaphor. I'm not really at a level where I can easily use a J-J dictionary, but it seems straightforward to me that affixing text to a word is a kind of attachment, so I'm not sure how the relevant sense could appear to be missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right about the meaning of つく. Here are some instances I collected.

In [this post](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1319438978?), the OP asks

> **あがつく**、おいしいものを、教えてください。 Please tell me about a delicacy that has the letter あ in its name.

The response is アイス(AISU).

[Another question](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14175483089?) asks

> **いがつく**あなたが好きなアイドルは？  Who is your favorite idol with the letter い in their name?

The response is 伊藤まりか(Ito Marika)、井上 (Inoue)、生田 (Ikuta)、生駒 (Ikoma).

As a result, I think the verb つく means "to be affixed to a word." Perhaps a derivative meaning of the first interpretation あるものと他のものが離れない状態になる in the dictionary.

Additionally, native speakers appear to assume that the verb means "to begin with (the letter)" if the position is not mentioned in the sentence. They phrase "a word ending in such-and-such letter" as [follows](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10253079965?):

> 最後に**あがつく**魚はいますか？ Is there a fish with a name that ends in the letter あ?

The responses are ティラピア, ラスボラ・ヘテロモルファ, チチカカオレスティア and so on.

Comment: Also, it does not have to be a single letter. E.g., jpのつくアドレス will be understood as *addresses ending in jp*.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to know — whether or not the assumption is "begins with", and if so, whether the subject can be more than one character or not. Per @sundowner's comment, it seems the answer is "it depends on context whether it means begins with or ends with", perhaps with a default of "begins with", and that it can be multiple characters.

Comment: I had to look up ラスボラ・ヘテロもルファ. Is it that common for native speakers to know random Linnaean names like that?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel
 I don't know if it is common for most native speakers. But in the example I gave, the poster introduced himself as a "biology enthusiast who breeds foreign insects" on his [homepage](https://chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/user/1150206648).